# PuTTY ssh tunnel (proxy) not supporting http(s) connections

Tags: windows, proxy, https, http, putty

I've setup PuTTY for using it as a proxy. here's a screenshot of my Tunnel panel for specifying a port to connect to

[image]

and then in Windows settings, typing in the address for proxy

[image]

and it only works for SOCKS connections. not HTTP ones. that's what I don't understand and am asking this question for: how to get PuTTY to setup HTTP proxy besides SOCKS? is it even possible?

- when I paste an image, it says the post should be clear without them, so here's an explanaiton for those who cannot view the images: I setup a dynamic tunnel with port 31415 in PuTTY>SSH>Tunnel panel, then setup proxy client in Windows' Settings for localhost:31415 (which was the address for the PuTTY proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and it only works for SOCKS connections. not HTTP ones. that's what I don't understand

They're two different protocols, which only happen to serve the same purpose, but each needs to be implemented separately in the program (if it chooses to implement it at all). It's like how POP3 servers won't magically become able to accept IMAP, or how SMB servers won't be able to accept NFS.

> and it only works for SOCKS connections. not HTTP ones. that's what I don't understand and am asking this question for: how to get PuTTY to setup HTTP proxy besides SOCKS? is it even possible?

It's not possible with PuTTY alone. PuTTY does not have any code for acting as an HTTP proxy server.

You would need to run a local HTTP proxy that itself is configured to use PuTTY's SOCKS port as the "upstream". In the past, Tor used to come with *Privoxy* and later with *Polipo* as an HTTP-to-SOCKS proxy translator (due to the Tor software also providing only a SOCKS listener).